# How many different configurations can I achieve by rolling the colomns of a 3x4 matrix of integers?

Tags: matrices, permutations, integers

I have a 3x4 matrix of different integers (3 column, 4 rows), the integers are 0..11
Only rolling of the columns are allowed. How many possible, and different configurations exists?

What is the result if we take the rows into account as sets instead of arrays?

Example
Original matrix:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11]
```

Rolling the last column downward by 1:

```
[0, 1, 11]
[3, 4, 2]
[6, 7, 5]
[9, 10, 8]
```

Rolling the middle column downward by 2:

```
[0, 7, 2]
[3, 10, 5]
[6, 1, 8]
[9, 4, 11]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have four positions (configurations) for each column, and hence $4^3$.

Comment: I think you mean $4^3$.

Comment: Ooops!  Of course.  (Thanks.)

Comment: And what is the result, if we consider the rows as sets instead of arrays?

Comment: Ummm... what do you think?

Comment: I have no clue, but I think it must be fewer.

Comment: Oh gee.  So you don't even understand my solution to your problem, then?